# Using regex in python to identify a phone number and count the number of instances

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm working from a CSV that contains a column with a bunch of different text (SMSText) and I'm using regex to determine if there is a phone number within that column for each record. If there is a phone number, then I want to count the total number of times that a phone number appears throughout. I using    `'^\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$'` to identify a phone number, but I'm not sure how to count the total. My CSV looks something like this:

```
UserID   SMSText  
0         Hi how are you?          
1         Call me back (999)-999-9999        
2         sounds good       
3         My work number is (888)-888-8888 
4         Thank you for your time         
5         Great, the best number to reach me is (777)-777-7777
```

So here the total number of times a telephone number appear is 3.

Here is part of the actual code that I'm using. I just can't figure out how to make it so that it identifies and then counts the total number of telephone numbers that appear:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
sms = pd.read_csv(open('file'), header=0)

regex_number = '^\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$'
sms.loc[:, 'word_count'] = sms['SMSText'].apply(lambda text: len(re.sub(regex_number, '', text).split()))
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Show a [mcve] that reads and identifies the phone numbers and whatever attempt has been made to count them.

Comment: okay I've added what I'm using above.

Comment: I'm not experienced in this area, but  I think you can use `re.match()` and it will either return nothing or something. Iterate over your lines and increment a counter if re.match returns something. I think...

Comment: Why are you using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)?

Comment: Use `len(re.findall(r'\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?-?\d{3}-?\d{4}', s))`